# Large label as a heading in Vaadin 8 web app

Tags: css, label, vaadin, heading, vaadin8

I need a larger piece of text to use as a heading to label sections of a form in a Vaadin 8 app using the *Valo* theme.

In previous versions of Vaadin, I recall doing this with a `Label` that I had somehow assigned a predefined style of "H1" (as in HTML "h1" tag) where that style was part of the *Reindeer* theme.

I tried and failed to do this in Vaadin 8 by calling `Label::addStyleName` and passing the constant [`ValoTheme.LABEL_H1`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/themes/ValoTheme.html#LABEL_H1).

Comment: This works fine for me with v8.0.5. Perhaps there's something fishy in your theme?

Comment: @Morfic You were correct, thanks. It does indeed work using the code approach I describe in my Question. Anyone interested can see my Answer here for a full example app. The problem that prompted my Question must be due to other issues in my real app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, indeed, calling [`addStyleName`](https://vaadin.com/api/8.0.5/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractComponent.html#addStyleName-java.lang.String-) on the `Label` and passing the constant [`ValoTheme.LABEL_H1`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/themes/ValoTheme.html#LABEL_H1) does work, as per the comment by Morfic.

```
final Label labelPlain = new Label ( "This is a plain Label in Vaadin 8.1.0 Alpha 6." );
final Label labelH1 = new Label ( "This is a 'h1' Label in Vaadin 8.1.0 Alpha 6." );
labelH1.addStyleName ( ValoTheme.LABEL_H1 );
```

Here is a complete example app, modified from the usual [Vaadin archetype](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/getting-started/getting-started-archetypes.html) `vaadin-archetype-application` in Vaadin 8.1.0 Alpha 6.

```
package com.example.try_h1;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.annotations.VaadinServletConfiguration;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;
import com.vaadin.ui.TextField;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.themes.ValoTheme;

/**
 * This UI is the application entry point. A UI may either represent a browser window
 * (or tab) or some part of a html page where a Vaadin application is embedded.
 * <p>
 * The UI is initialized using {@link #init(VaadinRequest)}. This method is intended to be
 * overridden to add component to the user interface and initialize non-component functionality.
 */
@Theme ( "mytheme" )
public class MyUI extends UI {

    @Override
    protected void init ( VaadinRequest vaadinRequest ) {
        final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout ( );

        final Label labelPlain = new Label ( "This is a plain Label in Vaadin 8.1.0 Alpha 6." );
        final Label labelH1 = new Label ( "This is a 'h1' Label in Vaadin 8.1.0 Alpha 6." );
        labelH1.addStyleName ( ValoTheme.LABEL_H1 );

        layout.addComponents ( labelPlain, labelH1 );

        setContent ( layout );
    }

    @WebServlet ( urlPatterns = "/*", name = "MyUIServlet", asyncSupported = true )
    @VaadinServletConfiguration ( ui = MyUI.class, productionMode = false )
    public static class MyUIServlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }
}
```

Screenshot of running that example app.

[image: Screenshot of app running, showing a plain Vaadin Label and another Label assigned the style name of constant ValoTheme.LABEL_H1.]

### `addStyleName` versus `setStyleName`

Be careful to call `addStyleName` rather than `setStyleName`. That second one clears all existing styles, replacing with your one style argument. This is not what you want, as you’ll lose all the existing styles assigned by the Vaadin framework.